# Trying to do a live search with mysql, php & javascript. My problem is specifically with the DB portion

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I want to be able to enter multiple words.  Here is an example of my php code that works:

```
SELECT
  id,oldssn,firstName,lastName,address1,city,state,zipCode,phoneNumber,email,agentid,status
FROM uniqclients
WHERE
    (
        id LIKE ('%ste%')
        OR oldssn LIKE ('%ste%')
        OR firstName LIKE ('%ste%')
        OR lastName LIKE ('%ste%')
        OR address1 LIKE ('%ste%')
        OR city LIKE ('%ste%')
        OR state LIKE ('%ste%')
        OR zipCode LIKE ('%ste%')
        OR phoneNumber LIKE ('%ste%')
        OR email LIKE ('%ste%')
    )
ORDER BY lastName,firstName ASC
```

This give be a valid data set.  Now I would like to add a 2 second search term, I think I am going to use ste&cov and the explode and trim them into an array.

I've wrote code that does the same as above and it creates a larger dataset.  What I need is to create a dataset on the first term and then check the second term against the first dataset to reduce the dataset results.  I simply don't know how to query the results of the first dataset.  JavaScript work fine.  Ajax works fine. PHP/MySQL gives me the resultant dataset for a single search term.  I can't figure out how to do a search on a previous search.

Comment: If you use `AND` with the two filters it should create a smaller result, not larger. You probably didn't group the conditions correctly. Show what you tried.

Comment: It should be `WHERE (all the ste checks) AND (all the cov checks)`

Comment: Sorry, had to run out to the Dr.  
Thanks @Barmar, that solved my problem!  Much appreciated.